# Need help with repeating/looping in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, loops, rows

I have this block of PHP and HTML:

```
<table width="57%" border="0" class="tabela_master" id="aps-cat">
<tr>
<?php    
while ($row = $db->sql_fetchrow($result_1))
{
      echo '<td width="33%" rowspan="12" align="center"><img src="../images/' . $row['picture'] . '" /></td>';
      echo '<td width="20%" align="right" class="tabela_master" style="font-weight: bold">Emri / Mbiemri:</td>';
      echo '<td width="1%">&nbsp;</td>';
      echo '<td width="46%" class="tabela_master">' . $row['firstname'] . " " . $row['lastname'] . '</td>';
      echo '</tr>';
      echo '<tr>';
      echo '<td align="right" class="tabela_master" style="font-weight: bold">Gjinia:</td>';
      echo '<td>&nbsp;</td>';
      echo '<td class="tabela_master">' . $row['gender'] . '</td>';
      echo '</tr>';
      echo '<tr>';
      echo '<td align="right" class="tabela_master" style="font-weight: bold">Datelindja:</td>';
      echo '<td>&nbsp;</td>';
      echo '<td class="tabela_master">' . $row['birthday'] . '</td>';
      echo '</tr>';
      echo '<tr>';
      echo '<td align="right" class="tabela_master" style="font-weight: bold">Adresa / Lokacioni:</td>';
      echo '<td>&nbsp;</td>';
      echo '<td class="tabela_master">' . $row['location'] . '</td>';
      echo '</tr>';
      echo '<tr>';
      echo '<td align="right" class="tabela_master" style="font-weight: bold">Telefoni:</td>';
      echo '<td>&nbsp;</td>';
      echo '<td class="tabela_master">' . $row['telephone'] . '</td>';
      echo '</tr>';
      echo '<tr>';
      echo '<td align="right" class="tabela_master" style="font-weight: bold">Email adresa:</td>';
      echo '<td>&nbsp;</td>';
      echo '<td class="tabela_master">' . $row['email'] . '</td>';
      echo '</tr>';
      echo '<tr>';
      echo '<td align="right" class="tabela_master" style="font-weight: bold">Interesi:</td>';
      echo '<td>&nbsp;</td>';
      echo '<td class="tabela_master">' . $row['occupation'] . '</td>';
      echo '</tr>';
      echo '<tr>';
      echo '<td align="right" class="tabela_master" style="font-weight: bold">&nbsp;</td>';
      echo '<td>&nbsp;</td>';
      echo '<td class="tabela_master">&nbsp;</td>';
      echo '</tr>';
      echo '<tr>';
      echo '<td align="right" class="tabela_master" style="font-weight: bold">&nbsp;</td>';
      echo '<td>&nbsp;</td>';
      echo '<td class="tabela_master">&nbsp;</td>';
      echo '</tr>';
      echo '<tr>';
      echo '<td align="right" class="tabela_master" style="font-weight: bold">&nbsp;</td>';
      echo '<td>&nbsp;</td>';
      echo '<td class="tabela_master">&nbsp;</td>';
      echo '</tr>';
      echo '<tr>';
      echo '<td align="right" class="tabela_master" style="font-weight: bold">&nbsp;</td>';
      echo '<td>&nbsp;</td>';
      echo '<td class="tabela_master">&nbsp;</td>';
      echo '</tr>';
      echo '<tr>';
      echo '<td align="right" class="tabela_master" style="font-weight: bold">&nbsp;</td>';
      echo '<td>&nbsp;</td>';
      echo '<td class="tabela_master">&nbsp;</td>';
}
//$db->sql_freeresult($result_1);
?>
</tr>
</table>
```

Now what I want is multiple records shown in the page. The web currently looks like this:
[image: Current look]

And what I want would look like this:
[image: Wanted look]

So my table would provide all my results from my MySQL query which looks like this:

```
$sql_1 = 'SELECT id, firstname, lastname, birthday, location, occupation, gender, telephone, email, picture 
          FROM pinkmoon_users ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 1';
$result_1 = $db->sql_query($sql_1) or die($db->sql_error());
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the LIMIT 1 in your SQL statement

```
$sql_1 = 'SELECT id, firstname, lastname, birthday, location, occupation, gender, telephone, email, picture 
          FROM pinkmoon_users ORDER BY `id` DESC ';
$result_1 = $db->sql_query($sql_1) or die($db->sql_error());
```

Comment: Thanks a lot buddy, I didn't notice that in my query.

Answer (score 0):

Your query retrieves only the last record from the database. If you want more, you should change the `LIMIT 1` to (for example) `LIMIT 10` or remove the limit contraint entirely.